# Missing standard header <format>

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I'm trying to use the standard header `<format>`, which should be part of C++20. I have GCC 12.2 installed on Ubuntu 22.10. Both CLion and GCC are unable to find the header; is there a way to manually install it, or am I missing something else?

The errors I'm getting:

GCC:

> fatal error: format: No such file or directory

CLion:

> 'format' file not found

Comment: You might not be running the correct gcc.  And if you are, you might not be specifying `-std=c++20`.  We can only guess from the information provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See C++20 library features implementation status

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features

Text Formatting is available in GCC only since GCC 13

Comment: Hmm. I thought that GCC had support for C++20 (except modules). I stand corrected. Thanks